# Converting Json data to Tabular form using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, data-conversion, format-conversion

I am trying to convert JSON data(Childnodes) to tabular format with a Customer column header. I am able to get the exact node via data ,but not sure how to convert it to tabular format. 
Code tried so far

```
$extensionfile = "C:\Test\Package.json"
$jsondata = Get-Content -Raw -Path $ExtensionFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsondata.dependencies
```

> ```
> @angular/animations               : ~7.2.0
> @angular/cdk                      : ^7.2.0
> @angular/common                   : ~7.2.0
> @angular/compiler                 : ~7.2.0
> @angular/core                     : ~7.2.0
> @angular/forms                    : ~7.2.0
> @angular/material                 : ^7.2.0
> @angular/platform-browser         : ~7.2.0
> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : ~7.2.0
> @angular/router                   : ~7.2.0
> @types/uuid                       : ^3.4.5
> alertifyjs                        : ^1.10.0
> angular7-material-table           : ^1.0.2
> animate.css                       : ^3.5.0
> bootstrap                         : ^3.4.1
> core-js                           : ^2.5.4
> fastclick                         : ^1.0.6
> file-saver                        : ^2.0.2
> font-awesome                      : ^4.6.3
> gentelella                        : ^1.4.0
> jquery                            : ^3.4.1
> material-table                    : ^1.50.0
>  moment                            : ^2.24.0
>  ng-knife                          : ^0.2.8
>  ngx-bootstrap                     : ^4.3.0
>  nprogress                         : ^0.2.0
>  rxjs                              : ~6.3.3
>  tslib                             : ^1.9.0
>  uuid                              : ^3.3.2
>  xlsx                              : ^0.15.1
>  zone.js                           : ~0.8.26
> ```

I required to this data in a tabular format with customer header, so that i can pass the data to another entity

`Library                   Version`
`--------                  -------`
`@angular/animations        ~7.2.0`
`@angular/cdk               ^7.2.0`
`@angular/material          ^7.2.0`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!!

### Answer

Managed to get the solution for it. It is via property - Name and Value with a loop

$jsondata.dependencies | Foreach-Object {

```
foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties)
{
    #echo $property.Name, $property.Value

  $property |  Select-Object @{Name="Application Name"; Expression={$appname}},@{Name="Type of Library"; Expression={"NodeJS"}}, @{Name="Library"; Expression={$property.Name}} , @{Name="version"; Expression={$property.Value}}, @{Name="CompanyName"; Expression={"No Data"}}, @{Name="Config"; Expression={$findnodelibs.FullName}} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append ./Test.csv
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that `$jsondata.dependencies` contains a single, multi-line string with space-padded columns? Take a look at how your question renders - the output format is not at all clear.

Comment: A sample of the json would be nice as well. Don't be stingy with the samples/examples.  ; )

Comment: Please show us what `$jsondata.dependencies.GetType().FullName` gives you. (looks like a hashtable or an array of PSObjects to me)